# Classify isolated singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem:**

> Classify the isolated singularities of $$  f(z)=\frac{\sin(z) - z}{z^3},\qquad g(z)=\frac{e^{1/z}}{(z-1)^2}.$$

**My attempt:**

$f$ is not bounded near $0$, hence the singularity at $z=0$ is not removable. Since $\lim_{z\to 0} z^m f(z)$ is $0$ for $m\geq 2$ and does not exist for $m=1$, $f$ also doesn't have a pole at $z=0$. Then, by classification of singularities, $f$ must have an essential singularity in the origin.

I don't think $z=0$ is an isolated singularity of $g$ but I'm not sure. $z=1$ is a pole of order $2$ since $\lim_{z\to 1} (z-1)^2 g(z) = e$.

Is what I have written correct? Is $z=0$ an isolated singularity of $g$?

Comment: Why is $f$ not bounded near $0$?

Comment: Ahh, you're right. Actually, $\lim_{z\to 0} f(z) = \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{1}{z^3} (-z^3/6 + z^5/125 -...) = - \frac{1}{6}$, so I guess $0$ is a removable singularity.

Comment: Yes, exactly. For (b): **Hint** What is the limit as $z -> 0$ along the positive real half-axis? The negative real half-axis?

Comment: It's $\infty$ and $0$ respectively. What does that imply?

Comment: @Travis, yes, Travis, what does that imply?